# Remove shelveset from local workspace

Tags: tfs, workspace, shelveset

Obviously I am too dumb to find the answer on google or even here. So please help.

I have unshelved a shelveset in TFS. Worked with this shelveset in my local workspace but know i want to get rid of the shelveset.
What I want is remove the files of the shelveset from my local working space and project. Even from the disc. Sure there is an easy way but at the moment the only way to do it i know is doing it manually - which obviously is not the way to go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the Undo Pending Changes option under the Source Control on right click at the Solution level.

[image]

This will not work with many developers as they will unshelve along with their own pending changes and an undo would clear all changes not just the shelveset changes. We struggled with this too a couple of years ago. Until we embraced the "checkin early and often" workflow. Today we would never open a shelveset with other files already checked out specifically for this reason. We work on code and check it in as soon as we can do so without breaking others. This works much better.

Comment: but then i would have to manually mark all files from the shelveset to avoid   undoing all the rest of my changes made in files not belonging to the shelveset?

Comment: Ah, we struggled with this too a couple of years ago.  Until we embraced the "checkin early and often" workflow.  Today we would never open a shelveset with other files already checked out specifically for this reason.  We work on code and check it in as soon as we can do so without breaking others.     I'm pretty sure there isn't a way to do what your asking.  Sorry.

Comment: well thanks, that definitely helps also - i was really afraid of missing a simple button i have to click

Comment: Sorry, no simple button to only undo the shelveset changes.  If this helps please don't forget to mark it as the answer and vote it up.

Comment: yes, i don't vote it up and mark it as answer, as it would be more confusing than helping. the real value is in the comments, not in the answer which might be misleading.

Comment: Many people won't read the comments, they only look for accepted answers.  So I added further details to the answer.  You can edit your question (or I can if you like) as well.